# Opengl-es calling onDrawFrame manually

Tags: android, opengl-es, renderer, glsurfaceview, game-loop

I am creating a game loop and I need to be able to call onDrawFrame (from inside the renderer manually) in order to "skip frames" if I find that I am falling behind on processes.

Currently I have a GLSurfaceView class that calls

```
setRenderer(glSurfaceRenderer);
```

With this set up I understand that onDrawFrame is called every tick.

I tried putting the above call inside a method so that I could call it from inside my game loop but on the second run of the game loop I crash with the message saying

```
setRenderer has already been called for this instance
```

Is there a way to call the renderer manually every frame

Will just calling the

```
onDrawFrame
```

method work properly.  Or is it not good practice to control the renderer in such a way when using openGL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see how calling `setRenderer()` nor manually calling `onDrawFrame()` in the game loop will solve anything. You should refactor your rendering calls to take into account the time it takes draw so in other words time based animation. In any case manually calling `onDrawFrame()` without a call to `eglMakeCurrent()` before any drawing calls won't work as you have both the renderer and game loop thread drawing.

Edit: Since you are using GLSurfaceView, you can call `requestRender()` from your game loop to trigger a render if you feel `RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY` is too slow for you.

Comment: I have already made a time based game loop (i'm sorry i didn't state that, ishould have) what i need is a way to make sure the renderer draws as an when its told to.

Comment: If the renderer is slow, then there isn't anything you can do about it without throwing more hardware at it.

Comment: Thats not what i mean at all :/ the tutorial i'm using is on [against the grain](obivam.net/index.php/the-android-game-loop) only problem is that the tutorial uses canvas and not GL

Comment: Ah fantastic i think that should work, i'll test it later. thank you :)